# Is the sannyasa lineage of Sri Adi Shankara Vedic or tantric?

Tags: vedas, vedanta, adi-shankaracharya, sannyasa

According a biographer of Sri Ramakrishna (Vaikunthanath Sannyal : Sri Sri Ramakrishna Leelamrita), in the Vedic age, there were no FORMAL sannyasa. It was started by Sri Adi Sankaracharya 'most probably' by following the 'Tantrika-Paasupata' system.

Is there any evidence of whether its just an assumption?

Comment: What is this Tantric Pasupata system? Is it the same as the avdoota sannyas mentioned in Mahanirvana?

Comment: @Rickross that is not clear to me.But Sankara's one is definitely not the abadhuta one:)

Comment: @LazyLubber how cd u understand?

Comment: @LazyLubber we must know the sources and processes of mantras and rituals

Comment: @Partha I take back my statement. I dont think there is any evidence to show that Sri Adi Shankara started a lineage of sannyasis.

Comment: @LazyLubber The dasanami sect started with Him

Comment: @Partha I could not find any evidence for that. If you have, let me know. Most stories about Adi Shankara, are just that - stories.